# Does the php file location in the LAMP server matter?

Tags: php, lamp, location

In the LAMP server, I can run the php file under directly the www folder, but much deeper (more sub folder)  I can not start the php file. Is there a setting for that?

```
[Thu Sep 28 02:50:35.987756 2017] [:error] [pid 893] [client 192.168.137.100:55784] 
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /srv/www/htdocs/test/tiltangle/dpd/query.php:12\nStack 
trace:\n#0 {main}\n thrown in /srv/www/htdocs/test/tiltangle/dpd/query.php on line 12, 
referer: 192.168.137.238/test/tiltangle/dpd/queryform.php 
root@web:/var/log/apache2# cat tail error.log
```

Comment: Please post an example to clarify your question!

Comment: Example: ..../www/info.php  ok    ..../www/test/info.php does not work.  Can not open in the browser. (So one sub folder deeper)

Comment: Please run `cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and post into your question

Comment: I should have start here. Can you check this?   
[Thu Sep 28 02:50:35.987756 2017] [:error] [pid 893] [client 192.168.137.100:55784] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /srv/www/htdocs/test/tiltangle/dpd/query.php:12\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /srv/www/htdocs/test/tiltangle/dpd/query.php on line 12, referer: http://192.168.137.238/test/tiltangle/dpd/queryform.php
root@web:/var/log/apache2# cat tail error.log

Comment: Please always enrich your OP so we can offer productive help

Comment: not your question directly (still is one of the errors shown), but have you enabled the php_mysql extension module?

Comment: I have found this solution too, but I do not find the php_mysql extension in the php.ini.    dll
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

Comment: I have some progress. So...in php 7 there is no mysql extension. It was replaced with mysqli. I corrected the mysql to mysqli_connect but still does not work. In the error log I have the same error message. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're seeing has no relation to location of your .php files, inside your DocumentRoot directory hierarchy.

The problem is you're calling the deprecated (for year) mysql_*() API, rather than the mysqli-*() API (notice the trailing "i" character after mysql).

This API has been deprecated for years + in PHP-7.0 was finally removed, so through PHP-5.6 you'd have received deprecated messages about this code, telling you to upgrade mysql_connect() to mysqli_connect().

As of PHP-7.0 all this old code was removed, so the old API calls now raise Fatals.

So the fix is to change all your API calls to the new API.

Do a find + grep on your entire code base + be sure you've changed all your files.

I you have many files you can use **phpcs** to find all incompatibilities + **phpcbf** to automagically fix most issues.

Comment: Meanwhile, I realized the same solution, but it was not enough to change the mysql to mysqli. The orders of the parameters was also changed.  I finished the replace, but I got a very strange error message. "  Undefined variable: filter in /srv/www/...../query.php on line 104"  This line has no problem under PHP5 (mysql).          'if (!($b1=="")) $filter=$filter." and  b>=$b1";'  It has got no sense.

Comment: Look into the phpcs program. This program finds incompatibilities in PHP code. The related phpcbf program, automagically fixes many of these incompatibilities, like changing mysqli*() calls to mysql_*() calls + rearranging calling arguments. These two programs are massive time savers, if you have many .php files to change.